# Dynamically inserting strings into prompt for unique API call

Tags: python, format, dataset

I have a dataset with industries and sub industries and I have a prompt. I run a loop for every industry and sub industry to pass it onto the prompt which then calls the API (which is not the problem)      The problem is that I CANT INSERT the industry and the sub industry into the prompt string...

```
print(industry + "........" + sub_niche)
formatted_prompt = promptpass.format(industry=industry, sub_niche=', '.join([sub_niche]))
           
content = generate_gemini_output(formatted_prompt)
```

I added `print()` before to make sure that the `industry` and `sub_niche` are corrects for the loop and they are so the error is definitely within the

```
formatted_prompt = promptpass.format(industry=industry, sub_niche=', '.join([sub_niche]))


def generate_gemini_output(promptval):
        
    max_retries = 3
    for retry_attempt in range(max_retries):
        try:
            convo = model.start_chat(history=[
            ]) 
            
            convo.send_message(promptval)
```

The prompts look like this:

```
            prompt1_1 = \
                f"Generate comprehensive  solutions for the '{industry}' industry, " \
                f"specifically within the sub-niches of {', '.join(sub_niche)}. Areas like ......" 

            geminioutput = convo.last.text
            return geminioutput

        except ..........
```

Was expecting `industry` and `sub_niche` to be inserted into the prompt but the prompt that is delivered to the API contains no values.

This is the output when I execute `print(formatted_prompt)`

```
Generate comprehensive solutions for the '[]' industry, specifically within the sub-niches of .
```

So the values were not inserted.

Comment: Please, make an effort to post readable content and well formatted code

Comment: if you don't get any error the values are inserted... did you check if `industry` is not an empty list (hence the `[]` in the output) and if `sub_niche` is not empty (which together with `join` returns the famous empty character)???

Comment: what about the output of `formatted_prompt`? Is it also wrong?

Comment: I made a print() before and after that... formatted_prompt does not contain industry and sub_niche.                industry and sub_niche care NOT empty and contain the right values...

Comment: ok, then the problem is _only_ `promptpass.format`, right? Of what types are they? `Iterator`s?

Comment: No error. It runs through. It just does not enter the values whatsoever